# How would you design this MongoDB Schema?

Tags: database, mongodb, schema

This is a fairly generic issue, and after just getting started with MongoDB I am trying to find which is the better option for this schema design.

Suppose we have those entities: **Product**, **Category** and **Order**

In an SQL scenarion, this would be the traditional approach for the schema:

Category -> Product -> OrderDetails <- Order
(A Category **has Many** Products and and each Product **has only A** Category | A product is in many Orders and An order **has Many** products, therefore we create an OrderDetails join table)

How should the same approach be in a MongoDB Schema?
Suppose a category **has at mos**t 10 to 12 **products only.**

**Scenario 1: Embedding Products into Categories:**

**Category:**

```
{
        "_id" : Category_ID,
        "name" : "Category description"
        "products" : [ { "product_name": "First product", "price": 500  }, { "product_name": "Second product", "price": 150  } ] 
}
```

**Order:**

```
{
        "_id" : Order_ID,
        "order_total" : 500
        "products" : [ { "product_name": "First product", "price": 500 }] 
}
```

**Scenario B: Embedding Category into Product AND having an arrays of product references in Order**

**Product**

```
{
        "_id" : First product,
        "price" : 500
        "category" :  { "category_name": "First category name", "description": "some random description"  } 
}
```

**Order**

```
{
        "_id" : Order_ID,
        "order_total" : 500
        "products" : [ product id1, product id2] 
}
```

Comment: Within SQL you'd want to have a ProductOrder incase the price changes, this is similar with MongoDB too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how many products each category has, embedding the product inside the category might be an ideal scenario (there's a 16MB limit on documents), and depending on the usage pattern, for example, do you always get a category and display the products inside of it? or is the usage pattern getting the product each time?

Another question to ask is, does the category need its own identity, do you have a page that lists more information about a category? Or is a category just a description? If that's the case then I'd personally treat it more as a tag, see the example below:

```json
{
  "_id" : id,
  "name" : "Product name",
  "description" : "Product name",
  "price" : 500
  "categories" : [ "Category name 1", "Category name 2" ]
}
```

As for the order document, I'd copy the whole product into the order, you always see similar patterns within say SQL, and this is because if the product changes like its price or name, you want the order to have a snapshot of the product at the time of the order. You don't want the price of the order to change after the customer has paid and it's been shipped.

```json
{
  "_id" : Order_ID,
  // "order_total" : 500 * this would be calculated
  "products" : [
  {
    "_id" : id,
    "name" : "Product name 1",
    "description" : "Product name 1",
    "price" : 500
    "categories" : [ "Category name 1", "Category name 2" ]
  },
  {
    "_id" : id,
    "name" : "Product name 2",
    "description" : "Product name 2",
    "price" : 500
    "categories" : [ "Category name 1", "Category name 2" ]
  }
  ]
}
```

I know this isn't an actual pure answer, more like a bunch more questions, however, I hope it gives some direction for your schema design.

Comment: This answer is very helpful, however I do have a question.  For the Order collection, in the array of products, you added an _id field for each product, is that truly needed? Considering if we add the whole product ( so no reference ) couldn't it just be skipped?

Comment: @jazzalltime it's not required but I'd keep it there to link it back to the original product that was select, similar to how many websites have the "buy this product again" feature